# Spring @PostConstruct in @Repository dao and @Service that extends dao

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

My application is using Spring Boot (latest version) and has a dependency which uses Spring (latest version).
The dependency has a `Dao` class annotated with `@Repository` that extends a couple of unannotated abstract classes up to [JdbcDaoSupport](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/support/JdbcDaoSupport.html).
Moreover, this class has a `@PostConstruct`-annotated method, that sets the datasource.

A secondary `Service` class, annotated with `@Service`, extends from `Dao`.

I'm finding that an autowired `<Service instance>.getJdbcTemplate()` - which comes from the above-mentioned `JdbcDaoSupport` superclass - gives `null`.

If I omit the `@Repository` annotation on `Dao`, the jdbcTtemplate is correctly set.
The same happens if I annotate that `Dao` with `@Service`.

A part from the fact that I may have annotated them both for no specific purposes - the whole application code is experimental, though I can see a situation where the main service extends the repository (dao) while a more complex one can implement its logic delegating to several dao's - is this forbidden by Spring or am I missing something?

## UPDATE

I added a `@PostConstruct` method to the service and it's not being called.

## UPDATE / 2

I tried autowiring the dao inside the service, but I get the same result; it seems to me a matter of `@Repository` and `PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor` where the latter replaces my bean with a proxy-generated one ([GitHub issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/24565#issuecomment-590408028)).

Answer (score 0):

You should Autowire DAO into Service instead of extend.

Comment: also let us know specific use case to extend DAO into Service layer.

Comment: Fine. But why shouldn't I extend it?

Comment: We are creating objects of DAO using Repository annotation & of Service class via. Service annotation. Spring will be responsible for both's creation. For objects created in this way spring injects them as dependency(aslo called dependency injection).

Comment: Try https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-hello-world-example/

Comment: However, FYI, I moved from _extending_ to _autowiring_ the DAO, but the result is the same. After quite some debugging, I found that the issue doesn't arise in usual service / dao usage - where _extendings_ works fine too; it's happpening in a Spring-manageg QuartzJob, where I'm autowiring the service, but I've found that when `@Repository` is used, the `PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor` replaces my bean with a non-postconstruct-ed proxy from `AbstractAdvisingBeanPostProcessor`.